# Update salary of person who handles most property

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me with this?

I need to increase the salary by £1000 of the person who handles the most property.

Staff:

```
staffno | salary
_________________
A1      | 12000
_________________
A2      | 9000
_________________
A3      | 11000
_________________
A4      | 3000
```

Property:

```
propertyno | staffno
_____________________
B23        | A2
_____________________
B76        | A2
_____________________
B34        | A1
```

---

```
UPDATE staff
SET salary = salary +1000
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT staffno
FROM property
GROUP BY staffno
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

So this is how far I got, but it updates all the values not the 1 i want it to.

Comment: First work out how to get the `staffno` of staff member with the most property. Then work out how to modify that to update the salary.

Comment: Add some SQL examples you've tried and people will generally help!  You will likely need group by, order by, limit (or max) and update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to count how many properties each staff member has.  Familiarize yourself with the COUNT function by trying this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Property;
```

You should see a result of 3 (based-on the data shown above), for each row in the table.  Of course, the total rowcount doesn't really do you any good...you want to know the higest count for each staff member.  COUNT is an aggregate or group-level function, which means that you'll have to do a GROUP BY query.  Try this:

```
SELECT staffno, COUNT(*)
FROM Property
GROUP BY staffno;
```

Basically, the "GROUP BY staffno" is telling MySQL to only show one row for each staffno, while COUNT sums-up the total number of rows for each staffno.  Now, you want your data grouped by staffno to be sorted by the number of properties they have, so add an ORDER BY to the bottom:

```
SELECT staffno, COUNT(*)
FROM Property
GROUP BY staffno
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

...which isn't the correct order either, so make sure you put it in DESCending order.

```
SELECT staffno, COUNT(*)
FROM Property
GROUP BY staffno
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Add-in a LIMIT 1 to get the top result, drop the COUNT(*) from the SELECT, and you should be able to figure-out which staffno has the most property.  Make that work, and then give the UPDATE a shot.  If you still need help, be sure to **edit your post with your UPDATE code attempt**.

Good attempt...you're so close.  All you need to do, is modify your WHERE to look for the "staffno" of the row that you're updating in the subquery, like this:

```
UPDATE staff
SET salary = salary +1000
WHERE staffno =
(SELECT staffno
FROM property
GROUP BY staffno
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much, and for actually teaching me, rather than telling me.

Comment: very complete; only comment I would make is attempt to use the exists instead of the sub-select since the OP tried using it.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 i have executed that query not working , give error Error: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'